# Choosing (key,plain) to produce zero state in middle rounds of AES encrypt

Tags: aes, reference-request, side-channel-attack

I was told in passing that (key, plain) pairs could be chosen to produce a zero state in AES encrypt in some middle round (say 5).  [The application here being to side-channel leakage assessment.]  However, I can't find any reference.  I assume such a thing could be constructed from various attacks on reduced-round AES.  Does anyone have a reference for the specific question (producing zero state) or for attacks that could be reverse engineered or refactored for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy to find such a key, plaintext pair.  All you need to do is:

- Pick a key, any key
- Expand the key using the standard AES key expansion process
- Start with desired block in the middle (e.g. the all 0 block after round 5)
- Compute the AES transform backwards (that is, in the decrypt direction) from that block
- The final result is the plaintext block.

I don't expect you'd be able to find a reference to this procedure - it's too obvious to be considered publishable...

Comment: OK, guess I was overthinking it.  The person who said this made it seem like they knew some magic trick.